# How is the MTR scale calculated?

Tags: networking

When pressing "D" within MTR, one sees a "Last n pings" side-scrolling output. At the bottom is a scale with the different max-times. I understand how this relates to the scrolling data.

`Scale:  .:1 ms  1:4 ms  2:10 ms  3:17 ms  a:28 ms  b:40 ms  c:54 ms  >`

How is this scale calculated? Periodically, it will change to reflect, I assume, new data. My guess is that it has to do with distributions of response times and that each level would represent a certain percentage.

I'd like to be able to look at the scale and say "95% of packets are returned within 28ms" for example.

How is the scale arrived at?

Comment: Look at the source.

Comment: Thank you for that, @IporSircer. I can understand RTFM, but RTFSC is a bit much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  far as I understand the source it is a square law.

Experimentally, with 7 scale items

- take the longest ping time
- take the square root and divide by 7² (for instance 166ms/49=3.388)
- then items for N=1..6 are N²*3.388

Take in account roundoff errors, for instance the displayed 166ms could be 165.5...